# How to prevent the creation of an RCS directory?

Tags: vc

When I enable version control for a certain file using RCS, Emacs 27.0.50 creates an `RCS` subdirectory.  I remember that some former versions of Emacs just created a `…,v` sidecar file instead.  How can I re-active that old behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

How embarrassing … immediately after my question, I found out that for achieving this, one just has to give an empty string for the sub-directory when Emacs asks for it.